# Same group of system of equation in the same line

Tags: align

I want to bring these two systems of inequalitys to the same line so that "or" is in the same line of the left to be $0<a<1, 0<b<1$ and the right be $-1<a<0, -1<b<0$?

```
\begin{align*}
0 &< a< 1\\
0 &< b<1\\
\text{ or } -1 &<a<0\\
-1&<b<0
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest you employ a couple of `alignedat` environments, with alignment performed on both pairs of `<` symbols. That way, it won't matter if the widths of the letters `a` and `b` (or whatever letters get used in practice) aren't exactly the same.

If `\qquad` provides too much horizontal spacing for your taste, you could try `\quad` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for alignedat env.

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{alignedat}{2}
0 &< a&&< 1\\
0 &< b&&< 1
\end{alignedat}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{alignedat}{2}
-1 &<a&&<0\\
-1 &<b&&<0
\end{alignedat}
\]

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The `alignedat`-based solution suggested above should be adequate as long as the widths of the letters or symbols in the midst of the pairs of inequalities (above: `a` and `b`) are fairly similar. If that's not the case, e.g., if `i` features in the upper row and `w` occurs in the upper row, it's preferable to employ an `array` environment, as `array` environments make it straightforward to center the `i` and `w` letters horizontally above each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for alignedat env. and \text macro
\usepackage{array}   % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary and relational operator symbols

\begin{document}
With \verb+alignedat+, asymmetry is noticeable:
\[
\begin{alignedat}{2}
0 &< i &&< 1\\
0 &< w &&< 1
\end{alignedat}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{alignedat}{2}
-1 &< i &&<0\\
-1 &< w &&<0
\end{alignedat}
\]

\bigskip
With \verb+array+, the letters $i$ and $w$ are now centered:
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt} % <-- important
\begin{array}{rCcCl}
0 &<& i &<& 1\\
0 &<& w &<& 1
\end{array}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{array}{rCcCl}
-1 &<& i &<& 0\\
-1 &<& w &<& 0
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple with `alignat`, which gives  you full control on the columns spacing:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}
    0 &< a< 1 & \quad \text{or} \quad -1& < a < 0 \\
    0 &< b<1 & -1 & < b < 0
    \end{alignat*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I'd be tempted to go with an `{alignat*}{4}` setup, though, and write `0 &< a &&< 1 & \quad \text{or} \quad -1 & < a &&< 0` and `0 &< b &&< 1 & -1 & < b &&< 0`, respectively, in order to align the right-hand components of the pairs of inequalities as well. (I guess this wouldn't matter if `a` and `b` had the exact same widths.)

Comment: @Mico: it is not really visible, from my point of view.